# Python faster way to insert each row of dataframe as one table to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, insert

I have dataframe like this with more than 300 rows

```
         name price percent  volume      Buy       Sell
1        BID   41.30 -0.36    62292.0     604.0   6067.0
2        BVH   49.00 -1.01    57041.0    3786.0   3510.0
3        CTD   67.80  6.94    68098.0    2929.0    576.0
4        CTG   23.45  0.43   298677.0   16965.0  20367.0
5        EIB   18.20 -0.27    10517.0     306.0    210.0
```

For each name I create 1 table in mysql. Here is my code so far.

```
vn30 = vn30_list.iloc[:, [10,13,12,15,25,26]].dropna(how='all').fillna(0)
data = vn30_list.iloc[:, [13,12,15,25,26]].dropna(how='all').fillna(0)

data.columns = ['gia','percent','khoiluong','nnmua','nnban']
en = sa.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://...', echo=True)

#insert into mysql
for i in range(30):
    macp = vn30.iloc[i][0].lower()
    #print(row)
    compare_item = vn30.iloc[i][1]
    if compare_item == data.iloc[i][0]:
        row = data.iloc[i:i + 1, :]
        #print(row)
        row.to_sql(name=str(macp), con=en, if_exists= "append", index=False,schema="online")
```

Is there anyway to make it faster for 300 rows?
Thank you so much. And sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

```
# import the module
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# create sqlalchemy engine
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}".format(user="root",pw="12345",db="employee"))

# Insert whole DataFrame into MySQL
data.to_sql('book_details', con = engine, if_exists = 'append', chunksize = 1000)
```

You can get all the details here: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/sql-insert-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for help. But my question is how can I make it faster because each row in dataframe become one table, not insert the whole dataframe into one table.